# Problems with reactstrap carousel indicators

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

```
<Carousel
  activeIndex={this.state.activeIndex}
  next={this.next}
  slide
  previous={this.previous}
>
  <CarouselIndicators
    items={this.items.map(item => item.id)}
    activeIndex={this.state.activeIndex}
    onClickHandler={this.goToIndex}
  />
  {this.items.map(item => {
    return (
      <CarouselItem
        onExiting={this.onExiting}
        onExited={this.onExited}
        key={item.id}
        src={item.images.big}
        altText={item.name}
      />
    );
  })}
  <CarouselControl
    direction="prev"
    directionText="Назад"
    onClickHandler={this.previous}
  />
  <CarouselControl
    direction="next"
    directionText="Вперёд"
    onClickHandler={this.next}
  />
</Carousel>
```

I have a bootstrap carousel component from this example [reactstrap carousel](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/carousel/). But when it renders I get error:

> Encountered two children with the same key, `undefinedundefinedundefined`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
>       in ol (created by CarouselIndicators)

But 'CarouselIndicators' items is unique values. Can anyone explain me where I was wrong?

Comment: It seems that in your items array some object have an id undefined, please ensure you have unique item values

Answer (score 5):

This is a reactstrap problem. The array you pass to  has to be an object array with field 'src' in it, like this:

```
[{src: 'unique string', ...}]
```

Since `<CarouselIndicators />` uses the field 'src' in the array item as the key for its items

Comment: can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Basically, the array you pass into <CarouselIndicators /> has to be an array containing objects, and those objects have to have a key called 'src', and the value of that key has to be a unique string, cuz <CarouselIndicators /> requires this key 'src', but it is not in the docs